# The difference between " considering formalities " with " standing on ceremony "

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, difference, idiomatic-language

Which one is used in a situation in which someone is regarding politeness or is shy to join for eating food in someone else's house?
And

Which is more common and friendly?

Comment: Hi Metissia, why are you only giving these two options? Where did you come across these?

Comment: Can you give a sentence in which you want to use one of these expressions?

Answer (score -2):

These are uncommonly used. "Considering formalities" makes perfect sense when used in the context of a sentence. I'd stick with that, unless you have a reason, as it is more common.

It's hard to say for sure without the exact paragraph.